# How to end a JavaScript started on a different page?

Tags: javascript, html

When adding this code to one page..

```
<!-- SCM Music Player http://scmplayer.net -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://scmplayer.net/script.js"
data-config="{'skin':'skins/black/skin.css','volume':50,'autoplay':true,'shuffle':true,'repeat':1,'placement':'bottom','showplaylist':true,'playlist':[]
</script>
<!-- SCM Music Player script end -->
```

It opens a playlist of songs, which works perfectly, but whenever u go to another page, it stays open, which is also good. Except on a certain page I want it to close, but being unfamiliar with javascript, html, or any code in general I have no idea how to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean a page loaded in a separate tab/window?  You can't do that, not without complicated client/server coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to end it, this is actually a security feature so you can't just modify other pages.

If you would be able to do so, an attacker one one page could e.g. easily modify the content on another, for example in order to get confidential data like passwords.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, considering it DOES close whenever I go to the ipboard admin login page, but I have no idea how.. Also, what should I do then? Because I need this to work somehow..

Comment: @user3196487 You can close the current window: `window.close()`. The only way (as noted by gnack) is to save a state in the server that another of your tabs shall close and to long-poll/frequently ask the server from any window/tab if the tab shall close. This, however, is quite complicated to do.

Comment: Can u look at my website, and see for yourself?
It's url is http://www.runerebellion.com/forums
it sends the music list there, and when you press the donate button, and go through the steps it doesn't work properly because of the playlist. So I wanted it to just close the playlist on the donate page.(After you select your package) (It only sends the script once which is on the forums page)

Comment: Please read above, had to make a new comment wouldn't let me edit.